# Fluxograma Dinâmico C#

Tags: c#

Tenho um programa para criar fluxogramas de blocos, cada bloco com múltiplas entradas e múltiplas saídas. Dentro de cada bloco (objeto) tenho uma sequência de operações matemáticas, que utilizam a entrada definida pelo usuário para gerar a saída, que por sua vez sera a entrada do próximo bloco, que está ligado por seta ao anterior, e assim por diante.

A parte gráfica está resolvida, ou seja, eu gero o fluxograma utilizado as figuras (utilizando `drag and drop`), porém preciso agora que cada bloco escolhido e ligado leia essa entrada definida pelo usuário, realize seus cálculos, e gere a saída. Os blocos são ligados por setas, como os softwares padrão de fluxogramas (ex: `bizagi`).

Comment: Bem legal sua pergunta, mas gostaríamos de saber mais detalhes técnicos: qual a interface gráfica usada? Como está a estrutura de dados de cada bloco? Quais códigos você já tem e o que exatamente precisa?